# pivot table to expanded dataframe in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, pivot-table

I want to build on a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082349/pivot-table-to-tidy-data-frame-in-pandas).

Let's look at some Python code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df_mat = pd.DataFrame(mat)
df_mat_tidy = (df_mat.stack()
                    .rename_axis(index = ['V1','V2'])
                    .rename('value')
                    .reset_index()
                    .reindex(columns = ['value','V1','V2']))
df_mat_tidy
```

This takes me from a pivot table (mat) to a "tidy" (in the Tidyverse sense) version of the data that gives one variable as the column from which the number came, one variable as the row from which the number came, and one variable as the number in the pivot table at the row-column position.

Now I want to expand on that to get the row-column pair repeated the number of times the pivot table specifies. In other words, if position 1,1 has value 3 and position 2,1 has value 4, I want the data frame to go

```
col row
 1   1
 1   1
 1   1
 1   2
 1   2
 1   2
 1   2
```

instead of

```
col row value
 1   1    3
 1   2    4
```

I think I know how to loop over the rows of the second example and produce that, but I want something faster.

Is there a way to "melt" the pivot table the way that I am describing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the parts of `pandas`' docs entitled ["Reshaping and pivot tables"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

Both [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) are all existing functions. It looks like you are reinventing some wheels.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rebuild a DataFrame from a comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame([i for j in [[[rec['V1'], rec['V2']]] * rec['value']
                  for rec in df_mat_tidy.to_dict(orient='records')]
          for i in j], columns=['col', 'row'])
```

It gives as expected:

```
    col  row
0     0    0
1     0    1
2     0    1
3     0    2
4     0    2
5     0    2
6     1    0
7     1    0
8     1    0
9     1    0
10    1    1
11    1    1
12    1    1
13    1    1
14    1    1
15    1    2
16    1    2
17    1    2
18    1    2
19    1    2
20    1    2
```